# You've reached the chart refresh limit for now. Check back shortly. What could be the reason?

Tags: reporting, charts

In the account detail page i have embedded two report charts. After refreshing the account page for few times i am getting an error on the chart that displays

> You've reached the chart refresh limit for now. Check back shortly.

Any thoughts why i am getting this error. I am using developer sandbox.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Limits on Report Charts in Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_embed_limits.htm&language=en_US) documentation includes this information:

> On detail pages, users can refresh up to 100 report charts every 60
>   minutes.
>
> Your organization can refresh up to 3,000 report charts every 60
>   minutes.

So it is by design, presumably because the charts are expensive for Salesforce's servers to render.